# How to display scores form Firebase

Tags: firebase, rest, unity-game-engine

I have a quiz app and I would like to display scores on last screen, however I have an issue how to do it.

Here' how my score script looks like:

{

```
//Zliczanie punktów i wyświetlanie wyniku
public static int pointssum = 0;
public Text points;
private string user;
private Text scoresboard;

USers users = new USers();



void Start()
{
    points = GetComponent<Text>();
    Posttodb();




}


void Update()
{

 points.text = "Poprawne odpowiedzi:  " + pointssum;
    
}

private void Posttodb()
{
    
    user = nazwagracza.Playernick;

    if (user!= null)
    {
        USers users = new USers();

        RestClient.Put("https://quizgame-inz.firebaseio.com/" + user + ".json", users);

    }


  
    
}

private void Getdata()
{
        
    RestClient.GetArray<USers>("https://quizgame-inz.firebaseio.com/.json?orderBy='scores'&startAt=0").Then(response =>
    {

        users = response;

    });
```

}

}

I tried to assign this data to user value but I'm getting error cannot implicitly convert type.

Can you please help we with this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to quote any errors received in full, including the lines/columns implicated by the compiler/interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

`users` is of type `USers` .. it is not an array.

You did probably mean e.g.

```
// Returns an array of USers
RestClient.GetArray<USers>("https://quizgame-inz.firebaseio.com/.json?orderBy='scores'&startAt=0").Then(response =>
{
    // get the first instance
    users = response[0];
});
```

or make `users` of type

```
USers[] users;
```

depending on your needs.

Due to the naming and description it sounds like you would want to do the latter since you want to display all scores, not only the best one.